# A question in electrostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

The following is from Problems and Solutions on Electromagnetism.

> > The electrostatic potential at a point $P$ due to an idealized dipole layer of moment per unit area $\pmb {\tau}$ on surface $S$ is
> >     $$\phi_P = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int \frac{\pmb {\tau}\cdot \bf{r}}{r^3}dS,$$
> >     where $\bf {r}$ is the vector from the surface element to the point $P$.
> >
> > (a) Consider a dipole layer of infinite extent lying in the $x-y$ plane of uniform moment density $\pmb {\tau} = \tau \bf{e}_z$. Determine whether $\phi$ or some derivative of it is discontinuous acroos the layer and find the discontinuity.
> >
> > (b) Consider a positive charge $q$ located at the center of a spherical surface of radius a. On this surface there is a uniform dipole layer $\tau$ and a uniform surface charge density $\sigma$. Find $\tau$ and $\sigma$ so that the potential inside the surface will be just that of the charge $q$, while the potential outside will be zero.(You may make use of whatever you know about the potential of a surface charge)

I can solve the (a) and the answer is
$$\Delta \phi = \frac{\tau}{\epsilon_0}$$
The electric potential is discontinuous across the $x-y$ plane.

However I don't understand the solution of (b).

It says the outer $\bf{E}$ is zero so that by Gauss theorem, $Q= \sigma 4 \pi a^2 + q =0$. Why doesn't it consider $\tau$ in calculating $Q$?

Comment: So what is the total charge of a dipole layer?

Comment: There isn't any mention about the total charge of it.

Comment: A dipole is (equivalent to) the limiting case of equal and opposite charges at infinitesimal separation. So a dipole's total charge is ...?